# Gulp file runs first time, but errors on watch task 'elixir' when saving a css file

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have been trying to get this working for hours and have searched SO and Google extensively but can't find anything similar, so apologies if this has been asked before. It's also my first question, so please forgive any formatting errors or bad practice (e.g. I was unsure whether to post my full Gulp file, so erred on the side of providing as much info as possible).

The problem: My gulp file goes through the full list of tasks on launching it, but if I change and save my main.css file it provides the error shown below...

My Gulp file looks like this:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var sys = require('sys');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('elixir', function(){
    return elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss','public/css',{outputStyle: 'compressed'})
    .styles([
    'bootstrap.min.css','sweetalert.css','font-awesome.min.css','main.css'
    ],'public/css')
    .scripts([
    'jquery.min.js','bootstrap.min.js','sweetalert-dev.js'
    ],'public/js');
    });
});

gulp.task('css', function(){
    return gulp.src('public/css/all.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 15 version'))
    .pipe(minifycss({keepSpecialComments : 0}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'CSS compiled, prefixed and minified.' }));
});

gulp.task('phpunit', function(){
    exec('phpunit', function(error, stdout){
    sys.puts(stdout);
    notify({ message: 'Unit testing complete.' });
    });
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        browser: "firefox",
        proxy: "http://localhost/laravelbp/"
    });
    browserSync.reload;
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('*.php', ['phpunit']);
    gulp.watch('*.css', ['elixir','css','browserSync']);
});

gulp.task('default',['elixir','css','phpunit','browserSync','watch']);
```

And the output in the terminal looks like this:

```
Tue Sep 20(16:00)~ root@:/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp: gulp
(node) sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
[15:59:18] Using gulpfile /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/gulpfile.js
[15:59:18] Starting 'elixir'...
[15:59:19] Finished 'elixir' after 246 ms
[15:59:19] Starting 'css'...
[15:59:19] Starting 'phpunit'...
[15:59:19] Finished 'phpunit' after 10 ms
[15:59:19] Starting 'browserSync'...
[15:59:19] Finished 'browserSync' after 48 ms
[15:59:19] Starting 'watch'...
[15:59:19] Finished 'watch' after 59 ms
[15:59:19] Starting 'default'...
[15:59:19] Starting 'styles'...

Fetching Styles Source Files...
- resources/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
- resources/assets/css/sweetalert.css
- resources/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css
- resources/assets/css/main.css

Saving To...
- public/css/all.css

[15:59:19] Finished 'default' after 474 ms
(node) util.puts is deprecated. Use console.log instead.

PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.
Time: 609 ms, Memory: 8.50MB
OK 
(1 test, 2 assertions)

[BS] Proxying: http://localhost
[BS] Access URLs:
---------------------------------------------
Local: http://localhost:3000/laravelbp/
External: http://10.0.2.15:3000/laravelbp/
---------------------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://10.0.2.15:3001
---------------------------------------------

[15:59:20] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] CSS compiled, prefixed and minified.
[15:59:20] Finished 'css' after 1.5 s
[15:59:20] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Stylesheets Merged!
[15:59:20] Finished 'styles' after 1.44 s
[15:59:20] Starting 'scripts'...

Fetching Scripts Source Files...
- resources/assets/js/jquery.min.js
- resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
- resources/assets/js/sweetalert-dev.js

Saving To...
- public/js/all.js

[15:59:22] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Scripts Merged!
[15:59:22] Finished 'scripts' after 1.72 s
[15:59:36] Starting 'styles'... ** << Here is where I hit Save on main.css**
[15:59:36] 'styles' errored after 187 μs
[15:59:36] TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/laravel-elixir/index.js:89:51)
at module.exports (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
at Function.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/laravel-elixir/tasks/watch.js:41:39)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at runBound (domain.js:300:12)
at asyncRunner (/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelbp/node_modules/async-done/index.js:36:18)
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
```

So, to sum up, the Gulp (version 3.9.1) file goes through the 'styles' no problem on the first run including loading the browser with any changes I've made to main.css before running Gulp, but if I make any changes to main.css and hit save while Gulp is running the above error shows up and keeps showing up every time I hit save.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Save your changes in main file first then run gulp.

Comment: Are you sure you have it setup right?  Aren't you supposed to invert this so you dont reference gulp and just use mix ?

Comment: Hi Love-Kesh. Thank you, but as mentioned that does actually work. The problem shows up when the 'watch' task is watching the .css files for changes when Gulp is already running. There's no problem when I save main.css first and then run Gulp. It performs normally when the .css file is saved first and then Gulp is run, but upon changing and saving the .css file the watch task triggers the above problem. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hi Nix. Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean where the task is defined, as in gulp.task('elixir'.....), or somewhere else? It works perfectly the first time it runs through though?